# On Update trigger, and using cursor

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

When you use On Update trigger, the update is probably for multiple rows.
MSDN said that using Cursors in triggers is bad thing for performance, what I should use then?

Thanks

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?  I've had a lot of success simply using the inserted and deleted tables to perform necessary operations for each row.  You can join on these or do other operations to get where you need to go.

Comment: Cursors are bad - period. Cursors in a trigger are a **guarantee** for performance troubles - just **don't ever do it**. Just use a regular, set-based JOIN operation of some sort - that's the way SQL Server "thinks" and acts - do the same and you shall be happy....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to update a column based in the rows updated, you can use a update statement joining the target table with the inserted virtual table. Of course, if your destination table is the same updated table, you must prevent recursive triggering, using instead of triggers, or updating the inserted table BEFORE the update happens.

Do you need code? Please be more specific about what exactly you need.